# Is there a "virtual guitar" app that can bend strings?

Tags: melody, note-bending

When a lick or melody comes to mind one the few times I'm away from a guitar, I use a virtual piano app to play with it and check how it sounds. But now I got an idea with a bend. How can i listen to it or play around with it without a guitar?

Comment: There are plenty of virtual guitar apps, but this isn't the place to ask about them. You might try searching the app store for your favorite device.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but you could away just sing it and record it, and then play it on the guitar when you get home

Comment: @Todd, I've searched a lot and haven't been able to find one that can bend the pitch. Maybe that part of the question wasn't so clear. I understand this isn't a place to ask for software recommendations, please read my question as: how can i play/test a melody with bends on the metro?

Comment: There are lots of options for portable, bus-powered controllers with bend controls. Also, tons of synth apps for all platforms have virtual pitch bend wheels, so you don't even need an external controller.

Answer (score 1):

Most piano-like synths have a *pitch bend wheel* (or simply "pitch wheel") or touchpad with similar control.

Any virtual MIDI app with track envelope capability ought to be able to attach a pitch shift to an envelope.

So look for apps/applications that allow envelopes or state that they have *pitch bend* capability.